# Where do I run DevTools code?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, har

I want to get a [HAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.har) file using [chrome.devtools.network.getHAR()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network). Specifically, I am using [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) within a [MahiMahi](http://mahimahi.mit.edu/) replay shell, and I want to inject `JS` that will dump the `HAR` into a file. The standard `JS` injection (`Selenium`'s `executeScript` method) does not work, because the page's `JS` scope does not include DevTools compatibility. With this in mind, I have a series of questions:

1. Where and how can I use methods like `chrome.devtools.network.getHAR()`? I have yet to find where I can run this, as the console when I F12 doesn't have it in scope.
2. Can I automate this process?
3. Can I get to this using Selenium specifically, or are there any other browser automation techniques that would work better? (Though I would prefer to avoid [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) because it's outdated)
4. Are there any other easier ways to automate getting a HAR file from a site?

Note: My code base is in Python

Thank you!

Comment: That getHAR method is from chrome extensions [devtools API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network) so you need an extension to run it. Or you can reimplement the entire thing using [devtools protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network) which should be accessible/executable in Selenium, but I'm not an expert on this. Also, try finding an existing solution.

Comment: Thanks! I've searched around for an existing solution and none seem to exist...

I am presently trying to make a devtools extension for this, so any pointers for a good tutorial would be welcomed. 

Regarding the protocol, the getHAR method isn't documented there so I don't think I can do that, as of now.

Comment: I meant you can reimplement [what getHAR does](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/extensions/ExtensionServer.js?q=GetHAR&l=437) by hooking the available protocol events and methods, which is basically what GetHAR does internally.